# Probability distribution over (space of) gaussian distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

suppose I have unknown Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$, and $N$ values generated by this distribution: $X_1$, $X_2$, $\cdots$, $X_N$. We can of course compute sample mean and variance to infer the ``most likely'' distribution. However, in principle any other Gaussian  distribution can lead to the observations, however with smaller probability.

Considering  all possible pairs $(\mu, \sigma)$, can we somehow quantify the relative likelihood of each pair? In other words, can we compute the distribution over all univariate Gaussian distributions given $X_1$, $X_2$, $\cdots$, $X_N$?

I'd be grateful for the answer, or for suggestions as to what area of maths/statistics deals with this question.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood function gives the probability, given $(\mu,\sigma)$, to obtain the sample $X_1,\ldots, X_N$:
$$
L(X_1,\ldots,X_N\mid \mu,\sigma) = f_{\mu,\sigma}(X_1)\cdot\ldots \cdot f_{\mu,\sigma}(X_N) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^n} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2\right).
$$
As I understood, you need to found what are more likely values of $(\mu,\sigma)$ given sample $X_1,\ldots, X_N$. This problem can be formulated only in the frame of the [bayesian approach](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bayesian_statistics). And to state this problem, we need to define prior distribution of $(\mu,\sigma)$.

If $\mu,\sigma$ are random values with prior distribution with pdf $p_{\mu,\sigma}(x,s)$, then posterior pdf of $(\mu,\sigma)$ given sample $X_1,\ldots,X_N$  is

$$
p_{\mu,\sigma\mid X_1,\ldots,X_N}(x,s \mid x_1,\ldots, x_N) \propto {L(x_1,\ldots,x_N\mid x, s)\cdot p_{\mu,\sigma}(x,s)} 
$$ 
Look also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Bayesian_analysis_of_the_normal_distribution

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But is  bayesian approach the only way? Suppose I compute sample mean and variance using my sample. Isn't it the case that normal distribution with these parameters  is the  ``most likely'' one to generate the sample, and this does not rely on bayesian approach?

Comment: No, this means, vice versa, that given $\mu=$ sample mean and $\sigma^2=$ sample variance, it is more likely to obtain given samples than for any other $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Your statement is also correct, but this does not mean mine is incorrect. Suppose you are given SampleMean and SampleVar, and you need to bet your money on just one distribution. Isn't it the case your expected win is the highest if you bet on N(SampleMean, SampleVar)?

Comment: Definitely not. The probability that sample mean is equal to theoretic mean is zero, so... We cannot ask whether some values of parameters are more likely than the others, if paraneters are some unknown constants.

Comment: I mean in the "density" sense, not in the "probability". If you know SampleMean, and  has to choose the bet on the true mean, then probability of TrueMean=SampleMean is zero. But considering a region of some small size x, you would bet that TrueMean=SampleMean+/- x. Same with the distribution. Wouldn't you bet that the true distribution behind a given sample is N(SampleMean+-x, SampleVar+-y)?

Comment: No. True distribution is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. If you are finding $P(\mu\in \text{SampleMean}\pm x, \sigma\in \text{SampleVar}\pm y\mid \text{fixed sample})$, you need to chose prior distribution of $(\mu,\sigma)$.
Plase stop discussion. You are asked for answer, you are got it. You can accept or not accept this answer. All that I wanted to write in the answer, I already wrote.

Comment: Don't tell me to stop discussion. If you don't want to reply, then just don't reply. I'm not sending you private messages, my questions are for everyone to see and possibly answer.

Comment: Why ask if you have your own answer, and you are so sure of it that you do not want to hear anything against it? You asked about maximum of $P(\theta\mid X)$, and the MLE gives $\theta$ which provides $\max_{\theta}P(X\mid\theta)$. Feel the difference!

Comment: 1) I asked because I don't know the answer. 2) If you read my post, you will see that what I asked is not about one $\theta$ which is ``most likely'', but also about relative likelihoods of all possible $\theta$-s

Comment: 3) ($\mu,\sigma$) are not random, they are constant parameters but unknown to me.   I need to assess the relative ``likelihood'' of each possible pair (mean, variance) given the observed sample of realizations.